# SQL "all in" group by

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I'm having troubles with some sql statement.

I have a table like this:

[image: Table]

I couldn't find any SQL form to do that but I want something like this:

```
SELECT 
   Col1, 
   CASE WHEN all(Col2 in ('A','B','C') THEN "auto"
        ELSE distinct Col2 not in ('A','B','C')        as Col2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Col1
```

Obviously the query is not valid SQL, so I explain what I want here:
If all registers in a group are A, B or C I want the column value to be "AUTO", in the other hand, if there is any column value different than A,B or C I want that to be selected.

So the result would have to be:

```
Col1   Col2
1      AUTO
2      R
```

Comment: What if there is an additionla record with `Col1 = 2` and `Col2 = Z`? Do you want do display both records `R` and `Z` for `Col2 = 2`, or just one?

Comment: Edit: It could be only one value diferent from A, B or C per group. Srry I forgot that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use aggregation:

```
select
    col1,
    coalesce(max(case when Col2 not in ('A', 'B', 'C') then Col2 end), 'AUTO') Col2
from mytable 
group by col1
```

If all values of `Col2` for a given `Col1` belong to `A/B/C`, then `max(case when Col2 not in ('A', 'B', 'C') then Col2 end)` returns `null`, which the outer coalesce turns to `'AUTO'`. Else, the maximum value other than `A/B/C` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to  your sample  seems you need the col1 with all the 3 values ('A','B','C') only and for others the value not in ('A','B','C')

```
select  t.col1 , t.check
from  (
  select  col1, 'AUTO' check
  from mytable 
  group by  col1 
  HAVING count(distinct col2)=3 
) t
inner join  mytable m on t.col1 = m.col1 and m.col2 in ('A','B','C')
UNION 

select col1, col2 
from mytable 
where col2 not in  ('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
-- drop table #t ;
create table #t (col1 INT, col2 nvarchar(32));
insert into #t values (1,'A'),(1,'B'),(1,'C'),(2,'A'),(2,'B'),(2,'R')
-- select * from #t

select 
    col1,
    case 
        when SUM(case when col2 in ('A','B','C') then 1 else 0 end) = COUNT(1)
        then 'auto'
        else MAX(case when col2 in ('A','B','C') then '' else col2 end)
    end col2_groupped
from
    #t
group by
    col1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the list of not *AUTO* cases first, then the list of *AUTO* that are not in the first list :

```
with datas (col1, col2) as (
  values
  (1, 'A'),
  (1, 'B'),
  (1, 'C'),
  (2, 'A'),
  (2, 'B'),
  (2, 'R')
),
not_auto as (
  select col1, col2 from datas where col2 not in ('A', 'B', 'C')
)
select col1, 'AUTO' as col2 from datas
  where col2 in ('A', 'B', 'C')
        and not exists(select 0 from not_auto where not_auto.col1 = datas.col1) group by col1
union all
select * from not_auto
order by col1, col2
```